# Tomcat 9 doesn't startup from Netbeans on a mac

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, netbeans, osx-elcapitan

I've put tomcat 9 on my macbook pro (El Capitan), it runs if perfectly from the terminal when I execute:
./catalina.sh start/stop

However, when I try to start it from Netbeans 8 I get the following error:
/Users/sigals/Documents/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M3/bin/catalina.sh: line 334: 127.0.0.1: command not found
/Users/sigals/Documents/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M3/bin/catalina.sh: line 334: Sigals-MBP: command not found
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

I tried to change the catalina startup script but that didn't change anything.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance